# python pandas filter and aggregate multiple columns and write into CSV

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to read a CSV file and count / aggregate on multiple columns

My input data is as follows

```
unique_identifier,date,flag1,flag2,flag3
a1,7/1/2017,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
a2,7/1/2017,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
a3,7/1/2017,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
a4,7/1/2017,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
a5,7/1/2017,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
a6,7/2/2017,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
a7,7/2/2017,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
a8,7/2/2017,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
q9,7/2/2017,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE
```

Am new to pandas and so far by reading various questions here looks like I need to use one or more of set_index(), .append(), , .join(), .agg()

I have the individual results but cannot get the new results I want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("flagdata.csv")

print (df["date"].value_counts())


df_flag1 = df[df.flag1 == True]
df_flag1  = df_flag1["date"].value_counts()
print (df_flag1)

df_flag2 = df[df.flag2 == True]
df_flag2 = df_flag2["date"].value_counts()
print (df_flag2)


df_flag3 = df[df.flag3 == True]
df_flag3 = df_flag3["date"].value_counts()
print (df_flag3)
```

I want to get a count of True Flags for each date to create a new csv file with the following result - date, total count, flag1 true count, flag2 true count, flag3 true count

```
date,count,flag1,flag2,flag3
7/1/2017,5,1,3,0
7/2/2017,4,0,2,3
```

Comment: `df.groupby('date').sum().astype(int).assign(count=df.groupby('date').count().flag1).to_csv('output.csv')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the rows by date and count and sum the flags:

```
result = pd.concat([df.groupby('date').count()['flag1'],
                    df.groupby('date').sum()], 
                    axis=1).astype(int)
result.columns = ['count'] + result.columns[1:].tolist() 
#          count  flag1  flag2  flag3
#date                                
#7/1/2017      5      1      3      0
#7/2/2017      4      0      2      3

result.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: Thx will try this out soon and let u know

Answer (score 1):

`groupby()` and created new count field reset_index as "count" then in seconf df `groupby` for `sum` of all `True`

```
df1= df.groupby("date")["date"].count().reset_index(name="count")
df2= df.groupby("date").sum().astype(int).reset_index()
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on="date")
df3.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks ! This answer also seemed to work ... just need to remove the extra indices values and duplicate date column

Comment: just upvoted ammy -:) , marked the other answer as correct as that too works and was there first -:) if u do get a chance do let me know what to do to remove the extra columns and the indices...thnaks agian !

Comment: Hey @Naresh MG i have done changes in above answer. last two line updated. instead of `concat` use `merge` and for `to_csv`  `index=False`.

Comment: awesomeness ! silly me, I have used merge before I should have fixed that...-;) I was trying index=False with contact...